# Preserving zoom level in Firefox

Tags: firefox, zoom

Is there a way to preserve the zoom level attained by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>+</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>-</kbd> in Firefox?

Let me be very specific about the issue at hand: I sometimes connect my laptop to an external monitor so I can browse with my wireless keyboard while lying on the couch. For that I need a higher zooom level, otherwise I can't read the letters on the screen as I'm further away than normal.

It's essential that I can change the zoom level with the use of keyboard only. I'm lying on the couch with my keyboard; getting up to do mouse stuff defies the purpose.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>+</kbd> /<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>-</kbd> would be perfect if only the zoom level would be preserved but each time I open another tab it's back to default 100%.

Here's what I have tried:

- Changing the default zoom level in `about:config`. This requires Firefox to be restarted which I won't have to do just because I connect another monitor.
- Installing the plugin [Default FullZoom Level](https://addons.mozilla.org/da/firefox/addon/default-fullzoom-level/) which enables you to change the default zoom level without restarting. This requires you to go: Menu > Add-ons > Default FullZoom Level and entering a numeric value. I don't know how to go the add-on menu by means of keyboard only and even if I did it wouldn't be handy ...

When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>+</kbd> a number of times I would like that to be the zoom level of all new sites I visit just up until I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>. Can that be done?

Comment: `I don't know how to go the add-on menu by means of keyboard only` See http://www.shortcutworld.com/en/win/Firefox.html#link_3

Comment: It doesn't say that there.

Comment: Yes there is. **Section 7 Firefox Features>Open Tools Menu>Add Ons**. Which by the way can also be opened with `Ctrl+Shift+A`

Comment: You're right - sorry!